# rewrite rule does not rewrite url as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with a CMS website, that normally generates readable urls. Sometimes it happens that navigation links are shown as `www.domain.com/22`, which results in an error, instead of `www.domain.com/contact`. I have not found a solution for this yet, but the page is working if the url is `www.domain.com/index.php?id=22`.

Therefore, I'm trying to rewrite `www.domain.com/22` to `www.domain.com/index.php?id=22` and I have used this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([1-9][0-9]*)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

I tested it using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be and here it shows the correct result, but on the website no rewrite is happening.

#### Begin: Rewrite stuff

## Enable URL rewriting

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(typo3|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|typo3conf|typo3temp|uploads|showpic.php|favicon.ico)/ - [L]

RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.dk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-alias.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([1-9][0-9]*)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC]

#### End: Rewrite stuff

Comment: Is it possible that some other rule is acting on the url before this rule ? Enable mod_rewrite logging and see what's going on.

Comment: Yes. That is possible. I will try what you suggest and get back to you

Comment: Any tips on how to do that? I have ssh access to the shared server, but don't know much about apache settings

Comment: Can you show all RewriteRules used on that site?

Comment: Yes - i added it to the original post

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, is working on my websites

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```